# proto_library() in Bazel BUILD file with cross-directory dependency

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

The following question might seem dumb but I'm struggling with it for a while.

Say if I have a `.proto` file in `/foo/foo.proto`, and another `.proto` file in `/bar/bar.proto`. `bar.proto` needs to import `foo.proto`. How can I write the `BUILD` file in both directories? More specifically, how should `src`, `deps` and `includes` in `/bar/BUILD` look like?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using the native `proto_library()`? IOW, do you have a `load()` statement that brings in `proto_library` from somewhere?